# read output text on calling spawn.send()

Tags: java, expect, expectj

I am new to ExpectJ Java programming. I downloaded jar's and able to do few `send()` and `expect()` methods. `send()` would fire a command on console and `expect()` would identify any prompt's so inputs can be provided. Expect only reads is there are prompts, and not other info. For example, if want to fire, `spawn.send("ls")` and get list of all file names and so certain action, is that possible?.

Is there way so I can read normal output of spawn.send("ls") for example, without expect which only captures prompts?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed capture the output stream:
It is one of the methods of the ExpectJ.Spawn class 
I am also very new to Java, but I got the output, however, I am still struggling on getting the prompt recognized as I get extra control characters from Unix so do not trust what comes after the second System.out.println (the sh,expect part)
the output works fine, just set it in a variable if you want, or if you use swing, send it to a textarea with a listener.

BTW! if you know how to do the expect without these bloody control characters, 1m,34 [001  and so on, I welcome your input

```
    import expectj.ExpectJ;
    import expectj.Spawn;

    public class myExpectinator {

        public myExpectinator(){
        }

        public void connect(){  
            try {
                ExpectJ ex = new ExpectJ(10);
                Spawn sh = ex.spawn("10.10.10.10", 22, "name", "password");

                System.out.println(sh.getCurrentStandardOutContents());
                System.out.println(sh.getCurrentStandardErrContents());
                sh.expect("~ $");
                sh.send("ps\n");
                System.out.println(sh.getCurrentStandardOutContents());
                //sh.expectClose();
                sh.stop();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);           
            }
        }
    }
```